# Is the a way to force Jekyll posts to use markdown formatting and ignoring css

Tags: html, css, markdown, jekyll

I took an existing static site using HTML that had an assets folder containing css. I'm running into issues when writing content in my _posts it seems like markdown isn't able to apply some of the css as if it's missing.  Where I'd expect my liquid {{content}} output to look like:

```
# H1
## H2
### H3
#### H4
**bold text**
*italicized text*
~~strike text~~
```

Header 1,2,3 match the css(there isn't a content mention of h4 so it just prints normal text). The strikethrough seems to work but the bold, italicized, and lists all seem to be broken.

I made a post that just included all the markdown stylings [here](https://blog.thornetlabs.com/myfirstblog)

Here is a [link](https://github.com/Thor-DraperJr/Thor-DraperJr.github.io/tree/main/assets) to my assets folder.

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to have just to the _posts folder ignore the css entirely and just use markdown defaults. Or does anyone have direction on what I could add to the main.css?

I've tried adding things like and changing it in as many combos as possible

```
---
layout: post
title: "My first blog post!"
category: [Personal, Tech]
excerpt_separator: <!--more-->
markdown: kramdown
kramdown:
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
  input: GFM
  auto_ids: false
  toc_levels:     1..3
  html_to_native: true
  auto_id_stripping: false
---

content
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Looking at the content of your "myfirstblog" post, it seems like it's doing what it should be doing. When you add `# H1` in a markdown file, you will get `<h1>H1</h1>` ...which is what you're getting.

Comment: @BradWest yeah I know that H1 is defined in the CSS but I'm wondering why bold text, italicized, and others aren't showing up. 

I was hoping to find a way to get just that post page to use the markdown defaults even if it was written in different text. Or possibly if there was a block of css that I could add to put in those features.

Comment: So, is the question "why is my CSS not working?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By convention Jekyll's Sass files are kept in `/_sass`. You would reference it in your `_config.yml` like so:

```yaml
sass:
  sass_dir: _sass
  style: compressed # http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style
```

Then inside your `/assets/css/main.scss` file you'd call the *main* file from the `_sass` directory like so:

```
---
---
@import 'main'
```

You need the frontmatter call, `---`, to let Jekyll know you want to process it.

If I understand your question correctly, making these changes should get you where you want to go.

Comment: This was great! I still needed to add a bunch to the css but this seemed allow changes

```css
/* Markdown Adds */
 b strong {
  font-weight: bold;
 }

 ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
 }

 dt {
  display: block;
 }

 dd {
  display: block;
  margin-inline-start: 40px;
 }

 th {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: -internal-center;
 }

 td {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: inherit;
 }

 em {
  font-style: italic;
 }

 strong {
  font-weight: bold;
 }

 ol {
  list-style-type: decimal;
 }
```